# How to display alert message while typing inside CKEditor? Using javascript/c# in an ASP.NET Web application

Tags: javascript, c#, css, ckeditor

```
<div>
    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="1108px" Height="383px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
</div>
<script  type = "text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function (e) {
                     e.editor.on('contentDom', function () {
                         e.editor.document.on('keydown', function (event) {

                                 if (event.data.$.keyCode == 97) {
                                    alert('Key Pressed');
                                 }                           

                             });                     

                     });
                 });

             });

    </script>
```

Above code that i have tried but not working. Please share if anybody knows. 
How to display alert message while typing inside CKEditor? Using javascript/c# in an ASP.NET Web application.

Comment: Does the function get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the event chosen. Use `key` instead of `keydown`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/H2szq/261/) is a fiddle example that works.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourtextareaid.on('key', function (event) {
                                //press a to see this working
                                 if (event.data.keyCode == 65) {
                                    alert('Key Pressed');
                                 }                           
                             });
```

Comment: I am not sure, for that example you can see that is the 4.2 version. Are you having trouble triggering the event?

Comment: glad to help! Please also mark this as the correct answer. It might help other people in the future :)